# How do I send a Salesforce custom notification to Slack Channel and not as a DM through the Slack App?

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app, custom-notification

As the title says, I am creating a custom notification (So that buttons and actions can be included in the message) to send to Slack through Salesforce. I am needing it to send when a record is created and include a button to view the record and claim ownership of the record. It seems as if custom notifications do not allow slack channel ID's to be inputted, rather individual user ID's.

How can I specify a channel for the custom notification to be sent to? Also, do custom notifications allow for custom actions to be created through these buttons?

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? i have similar requirement and need your input. response will be appreciated